# Envio de parametros en entre diferentes páginas sin URL

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Tengo un componente Home donde recuperó la información del usuario, me gustaría enviar ciertos campos de este usuario a otra página.

Ahora lo estoy haciendo por URL de tal forma:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/greenhouse', green._id, green.id_estacion]" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                <img src="assets/img/a.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">
            </a>
```

Pero me gustaria pasar mas parámetros sin usar la URL como ahora.

He estado mirando los input y output pero no termino de entender cómo usarlos en este caso, ya que solo veo comunicacion entre padres e hijos.

Podrían darme alguna pista?

Un saludo.

Comment: La comunicación entre páginas se hace con parámetros en la query porque si el usuario refresca la página pierdes toda la información

Comment: Hola,

Estoy intentando hacerlo por localStorage pero el problema es que la información que tengo que mandar esta en un ngfor en el HTML y tiene que mandarle solo el id que hago click y no se como hacer eso.

Comment: Deberías agregar el código de tu componente donde intentas guardar en localStorage. De nuevo te digo, usar parámetros en la query es la forma estándar a menos que la información no deba ser visible directamente al usuario por alguna razón. Honestamente me he encontrado muy pocos casos donde esa condición es verdadera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para la comunicacion entre componentes del mismo nivel se utiliza un servicio, el uso de servicio hace parte de las buenas practicas de angular, ademas de ser muy util para casos como este, tambien es acostumbrado a dejar todas las comunicaciones http dentro del servicio.

La creacion de servicios puede parecer mucha vuelta, pero una vez que entiendas como funcionan, escribirlos sera muy simple y veras la utilidad de ellos para organizar tu proyecto.

El contenido a seguir es un poco largo, pero te recomiendos lo leas e intentes entenderlo bien.

Debajo un ejemplo de como crear servicios, integrarlos a tu componente y modulo

```
// --------------- SERVICIO -------------------
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class MiServicio {

  constructor() { }
  /* Declaramos 2 variables en el servicio, estas variables podran ser accedidas desde cualquier componente.
     Simplemente inyectamos el servicio en los componentes que deseamos que usen estas variables y servicios
  */
  miObjeto: any = {};
  miArray: any[] = [];

  // Funciones que tambien podran ser accedidas desde los componentes
  getObjeto() {
      return miObjecto;
  }

  getFromArray(token) {
      return this.miArray[this.miArray.findIndex(item => item.token === token)];
  }
  // Funcion para modificar la variable, que puede ser llamada desde cualquier componente
  modificarObjeto(nuevoObjeto) {
      this.miObjeto = newObjeto;
  }

}

// --------------- COMPONENTE-------------------
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
// Importar el servicio creado
import {MiServicio} from './miServicio.service';
@Component({
  selector:    'app-mi-componente',
  templateUrl: `<h1>{{miObjeto.token}}<h2>`
})
export class MiComponente {

    miObjeto: any = {};
    // Inyectamos el servicio en el componente para usarlo
    constructor(private miServicio: MiServicio) {
         /* aqui asignamos a miObjeto declarado arriba con el valor que retorna la funcion getObjeto()
         de miServicio */
         this.miObjeto = this.miServicio.getObjeto()
    }

    miFuncion(token) {
       /* aqui asignamos a miObjeto el valor que retornamos de la funcion getFromArray() de miServicio
         esta funcion recibe un parametro
       */
       this.miObjeto = this.miServicio.getFromArray(token);
    }

    /* Aqui llamamos a la funcion modificarObjeto y pasamos como parametro el objeto 
       que querramos guardar en aquella variable
    */
    modificarO() {
         this.miServicio.modificarObjeto(this.miObjeto);
       // vale la pena mencionar que no hace falta crear una funcion para modificar la varibale
       // tambien podemos hacerlo asi: this.miServicio.miObjeto = {}
       // pero es una buena practica separar este tipo de cosas en funciones para mejorar la legibilidad
    }
}
```

Finalmente lo unico que queda es declarar el servicio como provider en el modulo

```
 // --------------- MODULO -------------------
 // Puedes tener tantos servicios como quieras, solo debes declararlos en providers
 // E inyectarlos en los componentes que quieras
declarations: [
    MiComponente
   ],

providers: [
    MiServicio
   ]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación. :D